# Developing for BlackBerry Playbook

Tags: blackberry-playbook

I am an Android developer and I wish to begin making apps for the BlackBerry Playbook. I understand there are two options available for developing for the Playbook: Android Air & WebWorks SDK. How do I decide which to use? What are the limitations, pros and cons of each?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are as of today only those two options available.  The others are all announced for future support, but none are generally available yet.

To decide between the two existing options, basically it depends on whether you are very strong in web technology (HTML5/CSS/Javascript) or not.  If you are strong there, you pick WebWorks.  If not, go with the AIR approach, which involves learning the Flash APIs and the ActionScript3 language.  ActionScript3 is Javascript-like, but closer to Java in many ways.  Not a bad language really.  Even has static typing, decent performance, etc.

Comment: But are there no limitations? Would I be able achieve the same goals using either options?

Comment: With the WebWorks approach, you can fall back on extensions written in ActionScript3.  That puts them roughly on par, to the point where what matters most is which you're more productive with.  If it's a toss-up, go with AS3 for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong, there are at least 5 options:

1. Adobe Air (same program would run on Playbook/Android/iOS, but has limited options)
2. WebWorks
3. Java / Blackberry
4. Java / Android
5. Native SDK

Since you're already an Android developer, you decide ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry about it.  In the near future, RIM will release an update for Playbook that allows it to run Android apps.  So just keep writing your apps the way you already are, and wait for that update to be released.

Comment: Any news on when they will open up the tools to convert Android Apps to run on Playbook? I did see a nice demo of the Android App Player here: http://blogs.blackberry.com/2011/05/blackberry-playbook-android-app-player-demo-video/

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are only zwo options to develop for the BlackBerry PlayBook:

- [Adobe AIR](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/tablet/adobe.jsp)
- [WebWorks](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/tablet/webworks.jsp)

But RIM announced that sometime during summer they are going to update the PlayBook to allow Apps written for Android and in their BlackBerry-Java.

Because Adobe AIR allows you to create a Native Interface it's also possible to use that to create Apps.